# Is the $\mathbb F_{p^n}((x,y))$ a local field?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, local-field

Let $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ be a finite field of characteristic $p$, then we can define discrete valuation $v_p$ in $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}((x))$ by
$$ v_p(f):=\min \{n~|~a_n \neq 0\}, $$
where $f(x)=\sum_{n \geq i} a_n x^n \in \mathbb{F}_{p^n}((x))$.

This may be called a one-dimensional local field known as the field of formal Laurent power series.

I am interested if there are suitable generalisations of $\mathbb F_{p^n}((x))$ to more than one variable. For example, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher_local_field) I see $\mathbb F_{p^n}((x))((y))$ is a two-dimensional local field.

- Is $\mathbb F_{p^n}((x))((y)) \cong \mathbb F_{p^n}((x, y))$?

Consider the field $\mathbb F_{p^n}((x,y))$ of formal Laurent power series in $x$ and $y$. To show $\mathbb F_{p^n}((x,y))$ is a local field, at first, we need to define a discrete valuation. If $f(x,y)=\sum_{m \geq i, \\n \geq j} a_{mn} x^m y^n \in \mathbb F_{p^n}((x,y))$, then I guess such a valuation is
$$v_p(f)=\min\{m,n~|~a_{mn} \neq 0\}.$$

We have to show it satisfies the properties of valuation as follows:

- (multiplicativity): Let $f(x,y)=\sum_{m,n} a_{mn}x^my^n \in \mathbb F_{p^n}((x,y))$ and $g(x,y)=\sum_{m,n}b_{mn}x^my^n \in \mathbb F_{p^n}((x,y))$, then $$fg=\sum_{m,n}c_{mn}x^my^n, ~\text{where}~c_{mn}=\sum_{k=0}^{i}a_{kj}b_{i-k,j}.$$
  I have checked particular examples, giving $v_p(fg)=v_p(f)+v_p(g)$. I think it is multiplicative.

I have not checked if $v_p(f+g) \geq \min \{v_p(f), v_p(g)\}$ holds.

I would like to get your comments if $\mathbb F_{p^n}((x,y))$ is really a local field. We know $\mathbb F_{p^n}((x))((y))$ is a local field.

Comment: According to the usual definition of a local field (i.e. one complete with respect to a discrete valuation), when $k$ is a finite field and $n=1$. If you're using a different definition (or using a different concept), you need to make that clear in your post.

Comment: @HankScorpio, can we define a valuation on $\mathbb F_{p^n}((x,y))$ such that it is a local field? I have tried the above. Besides that, $\mathbb F_{p^n}((x))((y))$ is a local field. Is $\mathbb F_{p^n}((x,y)) \cong \mathbb F_{p^n}((x))((y))$?

Comment: No, no, and no. It's extremely classical that the local fields are exactly $\Bbb R$, $\Bbb C$, or finite extensions of $\Bbb Q_p$ or $\Bbb F_p((t))$. Please look in a reasonable reference book before posting here.

Comment: @HankScorpio, yes, those you mentioned classical I am aware of those. My question was if there are generalization of field of Laurent series in several variables? Can you please explain the differences between $F_p((x,y))$ and $F_p((x))((y))$? The first one consists of power series in $y$ with coefficients another power series in $x$. But how they are different from each other?

Comment: What exactly is your definition of $k((x,y))$ for a field $k$?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, $k((x,y))$ is the field of fraction of the power series ring $k[[x,y]]$,

Comment: Haha, so what is the definition of "the power series ring $k[[x,y]]$?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, i mean "ring of formal power series". That is, $k[[x,y]]$ is the ring of formal power series while $k((x,y))$ is the field of fraction of $k[[x,y]]$. One might say, $k((x,y))$ is the ring "formal Laurent power series"

Comment: Oh well. https://mathoverflow.net/a/23568/27465

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, thank you for pointing out that interesting post. So to be safe we should say $k((x,y))$ is the field of fraction of $k[[x,y]]$ or quotient field. Anyway, but I don't see substantial study on this big field. I want to understand it's automorphisms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in [Pete L. Clark's answer to the MathOverflow thread "Examples of Common False Beliefs in Mathematics"](https://mathoverflow.net/a/23568/27465), and comments to it, for any field $k$, there is a proper inclusion of fields

$$k((x,y)) \subsetneq k((x))((y))$$

where the left hand side is, by definition, the quotient field of $k[[x,y]]$, while the right hand side, properly written $\color{red}(k((x))\color{red})((y))$, is the field of formal Laurent series in $y$ over the ("coefficient") field of formal Laurent series in $x$.

In fact, there is a bit of discussion there showing that while e.g. the element

$$\sum_{i\ge 0} x^{-i}y^{i}$$

somewhat surprisingly does lie in the left hand side (it is $=\frac{x}{x-y}$), but the upgraded example

$$\sum_{i\ge 0} x^{-i^2}y^{i}$$

does not. (More abstractly, one can check that actually, $k((x))((y))$ is "not symmetric in $x,y$", while the smaller field obviously is.)

---

By the way, the first example $\sum_{i\ge 0} x^{-i}y^{i}=\frac{x}{x-y}$ shows that your attempt of a valuation is not well defined because not every element of $k((x,y))$ van be written the way you claim it.

You can of course, e.g., take the valuation from $k((x))((y))$ (with the coefficients from $k((x))$ having valuation $v(k((x))) = 0$), and restrict it to that subfield. Pretty sure it will not be complete with respect to that valuation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In 2nd last para, not all elements of $k((x,y))$ can be written as $f(x,y)=\sum_{m \geq i, \\n \geq j} a_{mn} x^m y^n$. Why is it? Besides that, there might be possible to define other types of discrete valuation than what I tried to define, with respect to which the field might be complete

Comment: What is the standard form of an element in $k((x,y))$? I think any element $f(x,u)$ in it should be of the form $g(x,y)/h(x,y)$ where $g,h$ are power series in $x,y$ and $h\neq 0$. So $f$ may not be written explicitly as $f(x,y)=\sum_{m \geq i, \\n \geq j} a_{mn} x^m y^n$, where $i,j \in \mathbb Z$. Do you mean this in the 2nd last para of your answer?

Comment: Well yes, some of those elements $g/h$ cannot be written ("explicitly", or at all) as series of the form you want, with a lowest index with nonzero coefficients. --- Of course this does not exclude that there might be other valuations on that field with respect to which it is complete, but I doubt that there would be a discrete one which makes it local even in the broader sense of the word, because that would mean it would have to be isomorphic to a field that looks more like the "bigger" one here. Is there any evidence for that?

Comment: I agree. I don't know if there is any discrete valuation on it. I don't have evidence as I am at the beginning to explore on it. But I am surprised why did mathematicians not study much on such fields? What are their properties and what would be their automorphisms? I have not found many articles on it.